# Html2Canvas does not capture screenshots for IPad or Iphone

Tags: javascript

The html canvas is able to capture screenshots for browsers on MAC or windows laptop but when I am running the same code for ipad or iphone , it does not capture screenshots for browsers in ipad or iphone. Please provide possible solution.

```
var court = await html2canvas(divAbc[0], {
                    scale: 2,
                    logging: false,
                    useCORS: true,
                    allowTaint: true,
                    taintTest: false,
                    backgroundColor: null,
                    ignoreElements: (node) => {
    
                        return node.nodeName === 'IFRAME';
                    },
                });
                var img = court.toDataURL("image/png");
                capturedImages.push(img);
            }
```